# Unable to install Appium with WebdriverIO:Couldn't add script to package.json: Error: Error calling: npm pkg set scripts.wdio=wdio run./wdio.conf.js

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, appium, node-modules, webdriver-io

I am trying to install appium with webdriverIO ver 8

This is a [video I've done for clarity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xc3km8nxx2wx4q/Error%20on%20set%20up%20.mov?dl=0)

I answered the following questions while setting up webdriver8 configuration

```
===============================
 WDIO Configuration Wizard 
===============================

    ? Where should your tests be launched? local - for e2e testing of web and mobile applications
    ? Where is your automation backend located? On my local machine
    ? Which framework do you want to use? Mocha (https://mochajs.org/)
    ? Do you want to use a compiler? No!
    ? Do you want WebdriverIO to autogenerate some test files? No
    ? Which reporter do you want to use? spec
    ? Do you want to add a plugin to your test setup? 
    ? Do you want to add a service to your test setup? appium
    ? What is the base url? http://localhost
    ? Do you want me to run `npm install` Yes
```

It started installing and then I got the following error message.

```
Documentation: https://webdriver.io
@wdio/cli (v8.1.0)

Error: ⚠️ Couldn't add script to package.json: Error: Error calling: npm pkg set scripts.wdio=wdio run ./wdio.conf.js
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (file:///Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/WebdriverIOPOC/webdriver-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:506:31)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    at createWDIOScript (file:///Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/WebdriverIOPOC/webdriver-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:676:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runConfigCommand (file:///Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/WebdriverIOPOC/webdriver-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/commands/config.js:118:5)
    at async Object.handler (file:///Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/WebdriverIOPOC/webdriver-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/commands/config.js:126:5)


⚠️  Ups, something went wrong: Error calling: npx wdio config!
```

I'm totally confused.  What did I do wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I raised an issue with WebdriverIO Dev.  This is how [we fixed it](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/9529)